# Passing const wchar_t* and cont char* from VB to C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, vb6

Following is the method which I am exporting from my DLL

```
const wchar_t* _stdcall  EncryptAES(const wchar_t* value, const char* key)
```

I want to access this method from VB 6.0, kindly guide me so that I can achieve this.

Comment: I recommend reading Microsoft's manual [Developing DLLs for use with VB](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp) . The document was written for VB5 and never updated, but nothing changed from VB5 to VB6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now using VB.net so I will not post any code here, since I'm unable to be sure if it is correct.
But I suggest you to use StrPtr or VarPtr functions to pass wchar_t* parameter and ByVal for char*.
See this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205277) for complete guidance. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, the link is broken, can you update the article links, thanks.